# How do I forward a specific url to a specific mod_rewrite url on another domain?

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, virtualhost

I have moved a site from a sister operation to a subfolder on our main website. Our website location is is www.oursite.com, the sister operation was www.sistersite.com.

All of their site data is now at www.oursite.com/sistersite where /sistersite is a mod rewrite url being generated by Wordpress multisite which contains their data.

I tried to do a simple redirect

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sistersite.com
ServerAlias www.sistersite.com
RedirectPermanent / http://www.oursite.com/sistersite/
</VirtualHost>
```

But all this did was redirect all traffic to www.oursite.com to www.oursite.com/sistersite which is not at all what I want to do.

This is on Apache/2.4.39, editing the httpd.conf

I am uninterested in attempting to map sistersites pages to new locations, I can handle that from within Wordpress routing settings.

Comment: You said "I tried to do a simple redirect.." but "all this did was redirect", so it seems you succeeded :). What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: I suppose that is technically correct. But it's still not quite what I wanted to accomplish.

I just want to redirect the domain name which is now pointed at oursite.com to oursite.com/sistersite but I want the rest of oursite.com to work as usual.

Comment: Can you give an example like "when user types ... in address bar, I want ... to happen? Also, are both sistersite.com and oursite.com, running on the same server?

Comment: Yeah so, when a person enters www.oursite.com I want them to go to the base directory of the site. When someone enters www.sistersite.com I want them to go to www.oursite.com/sistersite I don't mind if the url is overwritten with www.oursite.com/sistersite. But everything I've tried so far seems to just force all pages on www.oursite.com/whatever to www.sistersite.com. 

I don't know if that's because /sistersite isn't actually a directory, it's routing done via wordpress/.htaccess rewrites or what.